# Reactive Cocoa Legacy - How to handle multiple independent signals in parallel?

Tags: ios, parallel-processing, reactive-cocoa

I would like to launch multiple independent networking request in parallel, and subscribe to when all requests are done (I don't care if they are completed or error).

For now, I used [`combineLatest`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/Legacy/BasicOperators.md#combining-latest-values). Thus the requests are made in parallel (as I want), but when a signal sends `error`, I got an error in the subscription.

I can't find an operator that allows me to launch multiple independent request in parallel, and listen to when all are done.

Sincerely

**EDIT**

In other cases (where I need to use the signals individually), I need to subscribe to the error. So I still need my signal to be able to `sendError:`.

*My use case is this:*

On the one hand, I have an app that can do a full synchronisation. This will launch all independent request. I need to know when all requests are done in order to dismiss the progressHUD. I don't care if my signals have done `sendError`or `sendCompleted`.

But on the other hand, I have multiple buttons, where I can relaunch individually each request, and in this case, I need to tell the user if the signal succeded or failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an answer, using the `catch` operator:
I add the `catch` RAC operator to all my signal, that make a new `[RACSignal empty]`in case the signal fails:

```
NSArray* allSignals = @[signal1, signal2, signal3, signal4];
NSMutableArray* optionalSignals = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (RACSignal* signal in allSignals) {
        RACSignal* catchableSignal = [signal catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
            return [RACSignal empty];
        }];
        [optionalSignals addObject:catchableSignal];
    }

return [RACSignal combineLatest:optionalSignals];
```

This does not change the nature of my individual signals, and I benefit from the `combineLatest`features.

**EDIT**

If anyone has a more elegant RAC way to handle the for...in loop, I am still interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rac_sequence` and `map` instead of a loop. Also, in your case using `catchTo` will work in the same way as `catch` while making code more concise:

```
NSArray* allSignals = @[signal1, signal2, signal3, signal4];
RACSequence *optionalSignals = [[allSignals rac_sequence] map:^id(RACSignal *signal) {
            return [signal catchTo:[RACSignal empty]];
}];

return [RACSignal combineLatest:optionalSignals];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
- (void)getAllItemsWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
        NSArray *signals = [self.allItems.rac_sequence map:^id(Item *item)  {
          return [[[self getForItemSignal:item] doCompleted:^{
                         //done
                    }] doError:^(NSError *error) {
                         //Change the button title to retry
                    }];
     }].array;

  [[RACSignal combineLatest:signals] subscribeCompleted:^{
     NSLog(@"All tasks are done");
  }];
}

- (RACSignal *)getForItemSignal:(Item *)item {
return [RACSignal startEagerlyWithScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler] block:^(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [APIClient getFeeForItemUUID:item.UUID
                         success:^(Fee *fee) {
                             [subscriber sendNext:@(fee)];
                             [subscriber sendCompleted];
                         }
                         failure:^(NSError *error) {
                             [subscriber sendError:error];
                             [subscriber sendCompleted];
                         }];
   }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: I see, you don't do send error, so the combineLatest goes in the completed. That's a good idea. But in some cases, I use the signal individually and in this case, I need to know if there was an error. Do you know if it is possible to achieve the same result without modifying the nature of my signals, but by playing with RAC operators?

Comment: @darksider like you are display button also along with each request?

Comment: @darksider Please do upvote if this is helpful. This is the motivation for us.

Comment: Yes, I will try your solution. I just wonder if sendCompleted will work after sendError, because I thought that by doing either sendError or sendCompleted, no other sendXXX could be executed.

Comment: @darksider All sendXXX will execute.